# How to align buttons in a line

Tags: html, css

I made 10 buttons using web template and tried to add 2 buttons using the code editor after

but they aren't arranged property as expected

```html
<div class="top u-align-left u-container-style u-expanded-width u-group u-palette-5-light-2 u-shape-rectangle u-group-1">
  <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-11" style="margin-top:120px;">
    <div class="u-layout-grid u-list u-list-2">
      <div class="u-repeater u-repeater-2">
        <div class="u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
          <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-12">
            <a href="../nav/nav_calendar.do?month=01" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-grey-80 u-btn-1">1월</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
          <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-13">
            <a href="../nav/nav_calendar.do?month=02" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-grey-80 u-btn-2">2월</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
          <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-14">
            <a href="../nav/nav_calendar.do?month=03" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-grey-80 u-btn-3">3월</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
          <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-15">
            <a href="../nav/nav_calendar.do?month=04" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-grey-80 u-btn-4">4월</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
          <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-16">
            <a href="../nav/nav_calendar.do?month=05" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-grey-80 u-btn-5"> 5월</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
          <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-17">
            <a href="../nav/nav_calendar.do?month=06" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-grey-80 u-btn-6">6월</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
          <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-18">
            <a href="../nav/nav_calendar.do?month=07" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-grey-80 u-btn-7">7월</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
          <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-19">
            <a href="../nav/nav_calendar.do?month=08" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-grey-80 u-btn-8">8월</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
          <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-20">
            <a href="../nav/nav_calendar.do?month=09" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-grey-80 u-btn-9">9월</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
          <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-21">
            <a href="../nav/nav_calendar.do?month=10" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-grey-80 u-btn-10">10월</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
          <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-21">
            <a href="../nav/nav_calendar.do?month=10" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-grey-80 u-btn-10">11월</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="u-container-style u-list-item u-repeater-item">
          <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-21">
            <a href="../nav/nav_calendar.do?month=10" class="u-border-1 u-border-active-palette-2-base u-border-hover-palette-1-base u-btn u-button-style u-none u-text-grey-80 u-btn-10">12월</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to put them together in a line by adding some css codes on the code above but have no idea where to put it.

Kindly share some idea to fix the problem. Thank you!

Comment: The code you shared doesn't reproduce the behaviour you describe; please edit the snippet to include the relevant "*[mcve]*" CSS.

Comment: Probably one of the container's classes has a limited width? You can check it via "inspect element" in your browser.

Comment: At a glance, seems your container size is `u-container-layout-11` and not 12. Have you also checked that their sizes are auto adjustable to fit?

Comment: Or for the last 2 items you have to update to class names: u-container-layout-22 and u-container-layout-23. These classes are probably specific to your project, so it's a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we don't have your existing CSS styling, it would be hard to tell how everything interacts with each other.

But it seems, you could add

```
display: flex;
```

to "u-repeater" class to get the desired effect. And further tweaking of flex could help you align them better.